# Подставить значения в массив php

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [barcode] => 48000479
        [code] => SK-1030-0049
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [barcode] => 31145499
        [code] => SST-1000-0066
    )

)

   Array
(
   [0] => 2
   [1] => 5
)
```

реально получить вот так

```
  Array
(
[0] => Array
      (
        [barcode] => 48000479
        [code] => SK-1030-0049
        [quantity] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [barcode] => 31145499
        [code] => SST-1000-0066
        [quantity] => 5
    )
```

)

Comment: а как вы узнаете к какому продукту какое количество присваивать ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, если количество в обоих массивах совпадает:

```
foreach($first as $k => $v) {
    $first[$k]['quantity'] = $second[$k];
}
```

где `$first` - это ваш первый массив, а `$second` - второй

Comment: Не `$second[$v]` а `$second[$k]`.

Comment: верно... Опечатался... Правильно будет $second[$k]